# A vector function $f$ satisfies the equation $tf ' (t) = f (t) + tA$. Calculate $f '' (1)$ and $f (3)$ based on $A$, if $f (1) = 2A$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions

A vector function $f$ satisfies the equation $tf ' (t) = f (t) + tA$ for each $t\geq0$, where $A$ is a fixed vector. Calculate $f '' (1)$ and $f (3)$ based on $A$, if $f (1) = 2A$

Idea: Is easy see that the equation $tf'(t) = f (t) + tA$ can be written as: $(tf(t))'=2f (t) + tA$.

Hence,  $$tf(t)=\int(2f (t) + tA)dt$$

But how do I find $ f ''(1) $ and $ f (3) $?

Thanks. Can you help me? Please!

Comment: Just differentiate both sides to see $tf''(t)+f'(t)=f'(t)+A$.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Yes, $f′′(1)=A$, but $f(3)?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Determine the integrating factor to find
$$
(f(t)/t)'=A/t
$$
so that
$$
f(t)=At\ln t+Bt.
$$
Then $B=2A$ per initial condition,...